# PHP losing anything between PHP tags when overwriting file

Tags: php

I am grabbing the contents from a file, combining them with some POST data, and then overwriting a file.  Unfortunately, when I overwrite, the new file is missing any PHP tags...and anything between them!  Is this a known problem?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['start'] == 1) {
    $menuFileContents = file_get_contents("examplesite.com/menu/index.php");
    $menuContents = stripslashes($_POST['blob']);

    $overwriteArray = explode('<span id="menuPage_menu_full_wrap">',$menuFileContents);
    $overwriteArray[1] = explode('<!--explodeflag-->',$overwriteArray[1]);
    print_r($overwriteArray[1]);

    $overwriteContents = $overwriteArray[0].'<span id="menuPage_menu_full_wrap">'.$menuContents.'<!--explodeflag-->'.$overwriteArray[1][1];

    $fileToOpen = fopen("../index.php","w");
    fwrite($fileToOpen,trim($overwriteContents));
}
?>
```

Comment: It appears your are accessing the output of the webserver. At which state, all the php could would have already executed. You need to open the file on the file system.

Comment: Just a tip: do not parse HTML with explode() function, use PHP simple_html_dom parser or DOMDocument()

Comment: Why don't you just store `$_POST['blob']` in a database (or even a text file) and read it in `index.php`? Seems a lot safer than dumping user input in a file that you are going to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` uses an HTTP request to get the desired page from the server which makes a request through the web server, not the file system.

When you get a .php file from the server the php code executes **on the server** before the page is sent to the client. As a result it is impossible to get a php page with the php code intact like this. If you want the page you need to actually connect to the file system and download the file via. FTP, SSH, etc. not HTTP.

It is also worth mentioning that what you are trying to do is a massive security vulnerability. Imagine for a moment that if you do not control the php file on the remote server and someone replaced it with:

```
<?php system("rm -rf /"); exit(); ?>
```

Even if you do control that file, a forged DNS entry etc. could still allow someone to run code through your server. Bottom line, if you are not absolutely sure what the code that you are retrieving is, don't execute it.

Answer (score 0):

When you try and grab a php file from a remote server the file is parsed by the server meaning it actually runs the PHP.  You can't remotely get the php contents of a file unless you FTP in or you set up the remote server to not parse PHP (which I'm sure you don't want to do)